# Setting the switch Node uses for running commands in Child Process functions

Tags: node.js, child-process, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
const child = child_process.execSync('python -c print(1234)', {shell:'bash.exe', encoding:'utf8'});
console.log(child);
```

I am running Node on Windows, but I want to run a command on Ubuntu using WSL. When I try above code, I get an error: `/bin/bash: /d: No such file or directory`. This is because Node is running in Windows, so it tries to run `python -c print(1234)` in the child process using `/d /c` switches. From the [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_shell_requirements) docs, I quote the shell requirements:

> The shell should understand the `-c` switch on UNIX or `/d` `/s` `/c` on
>   Windows. On Windows, command line parsing should be compatible with
>   'cmd.exe'.

Is there a way to set which switch Node will use to run commands in `exec()`, `execSync()`? Or maybe a way to "fool" Node to think I am running Linux?

Comment: Surely that would need to be `<PathTo>/bin/bash.exe`. I don't think it's the `/d` that is being complained about here, but rather the "relative windows path" to where `bash.exe` actually lives. And that's not `/bin/bash.exe` from a Windows filesystem perspective. Granted the execution eventually needs to get to `bash -c "python -c print(1235)"`, but the error is is because Windows does not know where `bash.exe` is.

Comment: It does know where bash is from PATH. If I set the absolute path, the same error occurs. If I for example set it to bashhhhh.exe, I get a different error in that it cant find the file.